# What will happen on SharePoint farm when an AD user is deleted

Tags: mysite

We have a SharePoint 2013 on-premise farm and sync to AD daily.
Around 10 days ago a staff was resigned and her account is deleted from AD. I have tested grant permission to this user and unable to do so. However, I can still search out her MySite from search center. Also, her name can be found in CA's user profile interface.

From my understanding, by default her mysite will be assigned to the 2nd site owner on the date of deletion. After 14 days her mysite will be deleted by timer job. It looks to me both are not happened. Is there something wrong in my farm setup?

Comment: Are the FIM services still running? Does your environment still sync correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need check Site closure policies in SharePoint...
check this below link for ref..

https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Site-closure-policies-a8280d82-27fd-48c5-9adf-8a5431208ba5?ui=en-US&rs=en-IN&ad=IN

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)